# Encrypt .NET binary serialization stream

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm studying encryption in C# and I'm having trouble. I have some [Rijndael encryption code](http://devbrasil.net/profiles/blogs/criptografia-em-c-aes) and it's working perfectly with strings. But now I'm studying serialization and the `BinaryWriter` writes the data of classes without any protection. I'm using [this code to test](https://denmartins.wordpress.com/2009/11/17/serializando-objetos-em-c/); is there a way to "encrypt the class", or something similar?

To clarify the question, here is my code:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\class.dat", FileMode.Create);
using (BinaryWriter sw = new BinaryWriter(file))
{
    byte[] byt = ConverteObjectEmByte(myVarClass);
    sw.Write(byt);
}
```

And this is how I read it:

```
MyClass newMyVarClass;
FileStream file = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\class.dat", FileMode.Open);
using (BinaryReader sr = new BinaryReader(file))
{
    // 218 is the size of the byte array that I've tested (byt)
    myNewVarClass = (MyClass)ConverteByteEmObject(sr.ReadBytes(218));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you can use [CryptoStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) inside ConverteObjectEmByte and ConverteByteEmObject. in the link there is example with Rijndael...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than converting to `byte[]` as an intermediate step when passing to different stream objects you can chain multiple streams together, passing the output from one to the input of another.

This approach makes sense here, as you are chaining together

**Binary Serialization** => **Encryption** => **Writing to File**.

With this in mind, you can change `ConvertObjectEmByte` to something like:

```
public static void WriteObjectToStream(Stream outputStream, Object obj)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
    {
        return;
    }

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(outputStream, obj);
}
```

and similarly, `ConvertByteEmObject` can become:

```
public static object ReadObjectFromStream(Stream inputStream)
{
    BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
    object obj = binForm.Deserialize(inputStream);
    return obj;
}
```

To add in the encryption/decryption, we can write functions that create `CryptoStream` objects that we can chain with these binary serialization functions. My example functions below look a bit different from the `Encrypt`/`Decrypt` functions in the article you linked to because the [IV (Initialization Vector)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) is now generated randomly and written to the stream (and read from the stream on the other end). It's important that the IV is unique for each chunk of data you encrypt for security, and you should also use a random number generator intended for cryptographic purposes like [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), rather than a pseudo-random number generator like `Random`.

```
public static CryptoStream CreateEncryptionStream(byte[] key, Stream outputStream)
{
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];

    using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        // Using a cryptographic random number generator
        rng.GetNonZeroBytes(iv);
    }

    // Write IV to the start of the stream
    outputStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

    Rijndael rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndael.KeySize = keySize;

    CryptoStream encryptor = new CryptoStream(
        outputStream,
        rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, iv),
        CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    return encryptor;
}

public static CryptoStream CreateDecryptionStream(byte[] key, Stream inputStream)
{
    byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];

    if (inputStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length) != iv.Length)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to read IV from stream.");
    }

    Rijndael rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
    rijndael.KeySize = keySize;

    CryptoStream decryptor = new CryptoStream(
        inputStream,
        rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
        CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    return decryptor;
}
```

Finally, we can glue it together:

```
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptoKey);

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\class.dat", FileMode.Create))
using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = CreateEncryptionStream(key, file))
{
    WriteObjectToStream(cryptoStream, myVarClass);
}

MyClass newMyVarClass;
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\class.dat", FileMode.Open))
using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = CreateDecryptionStream(key, file))
{
    newMyVarClass = (MyClass)ReadObjectFromStream(cryptoStream);
}
```

Note that we pass the `file` stream object to `CreateEncryptionStream` (and `CreateDecryptionStream`), and then pass the `cryptoStream` object to `WriteObjectToStream` (and `ReadObjectfromStream`). You'll also notice that the streams are scoped inside `using` blocks, so that they'll automatically be cleaned up when we're finished with them.

Here's the full test program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace CryptoStreams
{
    class Program
    {
        [Serializable]
        public class MyClass
        {
            public string TestValue
            {
                get;
                set;
            }

            public int SomeInt
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }

        public static void WriteObjectToStream(Stream outputStream, Object obj)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            {
                return;
            }

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(outputStream, obj);
        }

        public static object ReadObjectFromStream(Stream inputStream)
        {
            BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            object obj = binForm.Deserialize(inputStream);
            return obj;
        }

        private const string cryptoKey =
            "Q3JpcHRvZ3JhZmlhcyBjb20gUmluamRhZWwgLyBBRVM=";
        private const int keySize = 256;
        private const int ivSize = 16; // block size is 128-bit

        public static CryptoStream CreateEncryptionStream(byte[] key, Stream outputStream)
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];

            using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                // Using a cryptographic random number generator
                rng.GetNonZeroBytes(iv);
            }

            // Write IV to the start of the stream
            outputStream.Write(iv, 0, iv.Length);

            Rijndael rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndael.KeySize = keySize;

            CryptoStream encryptor = new CryptoStream(
                outputStream,
                rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, iv),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            return encryptor;
        }

        public static CryptoStream CreateDecryptionStream(byte[] key, Stream inputStream)
        {
            byte[] iv = new byte[ivSize];

            if (inputStream.Read(iv, 0, iv.Length) != iv.Length)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Failed to read IV from stream.");
            }

            Rijndael rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
            rijndael.KeySize = keySize;

            CryptoStream decryptor = new CryptoStream(
                inputStream,
                rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
                CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            return decryptor;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass myVarClass = new MyClass
            {
                SomeInt = 1234,
                TestValue = "Hello"
            };

            byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptoKey);

            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\class.dat", FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = CreateEncryptionStream(key, file))
                {
                    WriteObjectToStream(cryptoStream, myVarClass);
                }
            }

            MyClass newMyVarClass;
            using (FileStream file = new FileStream(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\class.dat", FileMode.Open))
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = CreateDecryptionStream(key, file))
            {
                newMyVarClass = (MyClass)ReadObjectFromStream(cryptoStream);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("newMyVarClass.SomeInt: {0}; newMyVarClass.TestValue: {1}",
                newMyVarClass.SomeInt,
                newMyVarClass.TestValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I tested here and it works perfectly with more than one class. Just one question, I changed the cryptoKey for security reasons, but I don't know what is this bIV, is this changeable? Again, thanks! :D

Comment: That's a good question. The IV should be unique for each file you encrypt for security (don't use the same IV again). I've updated the example to show it being randomly generated and written to and read from the file, which would be the usual approach.

Comment: I tried change, but I don't understand how generate a new IV. How to do?

Comment: Did you see the update to my example, where I have the IV generated randomly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the .Net Library had changed or just the code is wrong. I can't directly run the code written by softwariness.
Since that, I changed the code based on the answer so that it can be used correctly. Here's an example.

```cs
public class CryptoSerialization
{
    public static void WriteObjectToStream(Stream outputStream, object obj)
    {
        if (obj is null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj can't be null");
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(outputStream, obj);
    }

    public static object ReadObjectFromStream(Stream inputStream)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        return bf.Deserialize(inputStream);
    }

    public static CryptoStream CreateEncryptionStream(Stream outputStream, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        Rijndael rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

        return new CryptoStream(outputStream, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    }

    public static CryptoStream CreateDecryptionStream(Stream inputStream, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        Rijndael rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

        return new CryptoStream(inputStream, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
    }

    public static void EncryptObjectToFile(object obj, string path, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        using FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = CreateEncryptionStream(file, Key, IV))
        {
            WriteObjectToStream(cryptoStream, obj);
        }
    }

    public static object DecryptObjectFromFile(string path, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        using FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = CreateDecryptionStream(file, Key, IV))
        {
            return ReadObjectFromStream(cryptoStream);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // the original string "[This is an example key string!]";
    // I don't know if the length of the string has to be 32, but when I tried 64, it went wrong.
    string cryptoKey = "W1RoaXMgaXMgYW4gZXhhbXBsZSBrZXkgc3RyaW5nIV0=";
    byte[] Key = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptoKey);
    byte[] IV = new byte[16];
    using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngcsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rngcsp.GetBytes(IV);
    }
    //same as
    //Rijndael rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
    //rijndael.GenerateIV();
    //byte[] iv = rijndael.IV;
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>() { new Student { Name = "John", Age = 10 }, new Student { Name = "Marry", Age = 15 } };
    CryptoSerialization.EncryptObjectToFile(students, Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\testCrypto.dat", Key, IV);

    List<Student> newStudents = (List<Student>)CryptoSerialization.DecryptObjectFromFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\testCrypto.dat", Key, IV);

    newStudents.ForEach((stu) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stu.Name + ", " + stu.Age);
    });
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: The length of your cryptoKey is determined by the KeySize of the encryption algorithm. A KeySize of 256 (bits) results in a key of 32 (bytes). If you wanted a 64-byte key, you'd have to pick an algorithm with a KeySize of 512.