# How can I encrypt this BinaryFormatter Save/Load methods in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encryption, serialization, save

I have these two methods for Save and Load:

```
public void Save()
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + SaveName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    bf.Serialize(file, playerData.instance);
    file.Close();
}

public void Load()
{
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + SaveName))
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + SaveName, FileMode.Open);
        playerData.instance = (playerData)bf.Deserialize(file);
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

When I go the file location, all of the data are easily changeable. I want to encrypt it to make the player need more effort to change them.

Comment: How would you go about encrypting anything at all? It appears you are asking for a complete solution, which is not what SO is for.

Comment: I have an encryption method I have used for Json. But it takes string values as parameter. Do you know how can I get the string from the above code?

Comment: Why don't you use Json for storing the data? You seem to be using a *binary* serialization method for a reason, no?

Comment: Btw.: I flaged the Question as dublicate to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28791185/encrypt-net-binary-serialization-stream). You should check it out.